# how to get a const int pointing to a file's address

Tags: c, file, pointers, file-handling

I am making a program on bmp file parsing in c neon intrinsics. The functions require a const int pointing to the source file destination .. but by usinf fstream and fopen a get a file object pointing to the source. so how do I convert it to const int pointer

Comment: Neon intrinsics don't work on files, they work on registers/memory.  You have to read the file into memory first.

Comment: I am sorry if i sound naive, but how exactly should I do this

Comment: If you don't know how to read a file into memory, then you are not ready to work with SIMD such as NEON.  I suggest reading an introductory C programming book or tutorial.

Comment: thanks for the advice.but i've to complete the work. anyways i looked  it on net and learnt to store the file data in a buffer in memory..:)

Comment: Do you want a `const int` or a `const int*`?  They're very different -- and the former doesn't make much sense.  (I'm not sure the latter does either, unless the bmp is stored in memory as an array of `int`s.)

Comment: actually the neon intrinsic function takes const uint8_t* as arguement(uint8_t is the 8 bit long int type data type in c neon intrinsic).So basically I wanted to pass the starting address of the source file.but now I've got the solution I have to read the file in a Buffer in memory and I can pass the starting address of the buffer

Comment: @PrachiChouksey: yes, you either need to read the file into a buffer, or use `mmap()` (when writing for a platform supporting it).

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
const int *intFile = (int *)fopen("path-to-file.bmp", "r");
```

You can always assign a pointer to some type to a pointer to any other type using a casting, like:

```
int i;
int  *ptrInt  = &i;        // this doesn't need a cast
char *ptrChar = (char*)&i; // this does need a cast
```

In this case, `ptrChar` is pointing to "the first" byte of `i`. This "first" byte can be the LSB or the MSB depending on wether your machine use little endianness or  big endianness, respectively.

Note that making such conversions are very useful if used carefully, but involve low level concepts, and may be not safe.

Now, you can always assign a pointer to a const pointer of the same type directly:

```
char c;
char *pc = &c;
const char *cpc = pc;
```

So, there is no need to write `const int *intFile = (const int*) ...`

In the last example, `const char *cpc` means `c` cannot be modified through `cpc`, i.e., `cpc` is a "pointer to a const char":

```
*cpc   = 'H';   // error
cpc[0] = 'j'; // error
```

Comment: First of all, `int` and `FILE` are completely distinct types. An `int*` pointer to `FILE` struct (which is opaque by the way) is something completely random, and is of no use to anything (except for very specialized function which has wrong prototype and casts the `int*` back to `FILE*` internally, which is just plain broken). Also, in C there's no guarantee that `sizeof(int*) == sizeof(FILE*)` so the actual cast may be invalid as well.